# Looping over array with array length as condition

Tags: solidity

Say we have a contract with a dynamic state array `fooArray` of uint256. At the same contract there is a function with the following loop:

```
for (uint256 i = 0; i < fooArray.length; ++i) {
// Some code here, that does not modify array in any way.
}
```

Does checking the loop condition require reading the length of the `fooArray` from the storage on each iteration or it is not considered as reading a value from the storage?
Should I preliminarily save length of the array to a local variable and use this variable as a loop condition to save gas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created new contract and then executed it 3 times without temp variable and then again created new contract and executed with temp variable. Results from Remix Javscript VM and Rinkeby networks were precisely the same and **function with temp variable required less gas**. It is possible to read bytecode and [Gas Costs from Yellow Paper](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU) however I think it is quite clear that it is better to use temp variable.

**Solidity code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 
contract EstimateGas {
    uint[] public fooArray;
    constructor (){
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
            fooArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    function changeNoTemp() public{
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < fooArray.length; ++i) {
            fooArray[i] = fooArray[i] +1;
        }        
    }
    function changeWithTemp() public{
        uint arrayLen = fooArray.length;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < arrayLen; ++i) {
            fooArray[i] = fooArray[i] +1;
        }        
    }    
}
```

**Gas execution costs**

```
changeNoTemp()
1) 2965426 gas
2) 2948326 gas
3) 2948326 gas

changeWithTemp()
1) 2911461 gas
2) 2894361 gas
3) 2894361 gas
```

Comment: I got similar result using Remix IDE. Hower I come across with this pattern of iterating over an array in a code of many top-level projects. For example [here](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/ccb43f026f4ef25ba338073d02dec5c58123da32/contracts/protocol/lendingpool/LendingPool.sol#L501) at AAVE's lending pool protocol. So this got me confused and it is unclear for me why don't they preliminary store array length to reduce gas consumption. May be there is something I'm missing

Comment: In your AAVE's example it is used for assets array and it has "addresses of the assets being flash-borrowed". It should be very small array and temporary variable would give insignificant gas reduction. My guess is that AAVE wanted to have less code lines and it makes code cleaner, easier to read. Probably if it is necessary to use temporary variable to save gas then codes requires refactoring because smart contract should not have huge, expensive loops...